# Counting the number of thick regions which overlap a square

Tags: cg.comp-geom

Let $S$ be a unit square.
**As a function of $\beta$, what is the maximum number of $\beta$-fat pairwise-disjoint regions *with diameter at least 1* which can intersect $S$?**

Below, we give a figure showing that for $\beta=1$, the maximum number is 7. What about for $\beta = 2, 3, \ldots, n$?

Recall the definition of *fat* for regions in the plane. Given a region $R$, let circle $C_1$ of radius $r_1$ be the largest circle contained in $R$, and let circle $C_2$ of radius $r_2$ be the smallest circle that contains $R$. The *fatness* of $R$ is given by $\frac{r_2}{r_1}$, and we say that $R$ is $\beta$-fat, for $\beta = \frac{r_2}{r_1}$.

For example, if $r_2 = r_1=\frac{1}{2}$, then the regions are unit circles, and there are at 7 circles with diameter at least 1 which can overlap $S$ without overlapping each other.
In the figure below, we have depicted a unit square and 7 unit circles which overlap the square.

[image: overlapping circles]

Comment: The condition "circles at least as large as $S$" is confusing, and if you are talking about areas, a circle of radius $1$ is not as large as $S$.  Also, for the $r_2 = r_1 = 1$ case, you can put $7$ circles (one in the middle of $S$), am I stupidly wrong?

Comment: Your definition of "thick" is one of the standard definitions of "fat".  I assume you mean "the maximum number of thick disjoint regions **with diameter at least 1** that can intersect S", since otherwise there is no upper bound.  Tiny circles have thickness 1.

Comment: @JɛﬀE yes, that is exactly what I am trying to say. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @YixinCao I provided a figure which should hopefully clarify things.

Comment: @Joe As my picture shows, seven circles are possible.  The point is: two circles (almost) tangent to two opposite points.  My drawing is always bad, but I hope the graph is helpful.

Comment: @Joe: If you rotate the circles slightly around the center of the square, all seven circles intersect the square.

Comment: @YixinCao I don't see your figure, but I'm drawing up another one that pictures what you and J$\epsilon$ffe pointed out

Comment: @JɛﬀE I see what you and YixinCao were saying, and I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the maximum number of pairwise disjoint fat regions which overlap the square should be strongly related to circle packing.

The worst-case shape for a region is something like a "ball & chain". Below I have depicted such a region for $\beta=2$ with diameter 1

[image: ball-chain].

and these can pack within distance 1 of the unit square obviously much more tightly than I've depicted them.

[image: ball-chain-packing]

Note that the actual ball & chain region is defined by the green area, and the outer circle is just a guide to depict the fact that these regions have fatness 2. In fact, the chain part of the region, can "bend" to allow more regions to be packed.

[image]